# Java diamond-shape isometric map tile pick

Tags: java, cursor, mouse, isometric

I'm programming an isometric game in Java, but I stuck when I wanted to get the tile, where the mouse pointing.

Is there a way, to calculate it?

here is the code for rendering

```
int posX = 10;
int posY = 0;      
static int beginY = 500-72;
static int beginX = 800-36;
static int newLineY = 60;
static int newLineX = 200;    

posY = ((0+1)*9)-9+beginY/2;
posX = ((beginX)/2)+18-(18*(0+1));

for (int y = 0; y <= world.length-1; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= world[y].length-1; x++) {
        if (world[y][x] == 1) {
            g.drawImage(grass, posX, posY, null);
            posX += 18;
            posY += 9;
        } else if (world[y][x] == 2) {
            g.drawImage(wall, posX, posY-38, null);
            posX += 18;
            posY += 9;
        } else if (world[y][x] == 3) {
            g.drawImage(stone, posX, posY, null);
            posX += 18;
            posY += 9;
        } else if (world[y][x] == 4) {
            g.drawImage(water, posX, posY, null);
            posX += 18;
            posY += 9;
        } else {
            posX += 18;
            posY += 9;
        }
        if ((y-pPosX) * (y-pPosX) + (x-pPosY) * (x-pPosY) <= 3*3 && world[y][x] != 0 && world[y][x] != 2 && world[y][x] != 4) {
            g.drawImage(hollow, posX-18, posY-9, null);
        }
        if (y == selectedX && x == selectedY) {
            g.drawImage(selected, posX-18, posY-9, null);
        }
        if (world2[y][x] == 9) {
            g.drawImage(character, posX-18, posY-53, null);
        }
    }
    posY = ((y+1)*9)+beginY/2;
    posX = ((beginX)/2)-(18*(y+1));
}
```

This is the result. `beginX` and `beginY` start at the top corner of the diamond:

[image: isometric tile map]

Comment: That's not enough information, please clarify. e.g are you using an engine, some openGL implementation or a swing based GUI (with Canvas)? It would be best if you could add some code. How do you load a tile? is it an Image or do you paint it directly?

Comment: I dont use any engine, nor OpenGL, only JFrame.

Comment: I create a Buffered Image, then i define the path for it. I insert the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First register a MouseListener to your panel (the panel where you want to draw your tiles).
Now, according to your rendering code you actually "*know*" where each tile starts. So all you have to do is calculate which tile was clicked.

```
JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
gamePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        int x=event.getX();
        int y=event.getY();
        System.out.println("clicked at ("+x+","+y+")");  //these co-ords are relative to the your gamePanel           
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I changed to code above, it wasn't correct. But I am sure you'll figure it out. So above code shows you how to add a `MouseListener` to your panel/frame. And if it works, you should be able to see in the console where you click.

Now you only have to calculate which tile was clicked:

```
(x,y) --> + - - - 
          '    /\
          '  /    \
          '/        \
           \        /
             \    /
               \/     + <-- (x+36, y+18)
```

your mouse pointer needs to be somewhere between the two points `(x,y)` and `(x+36, y+18)`.
Of course there is the additional problem that someone could click somewhere between (x,y) and (y+36, y+18) but still not click on the tile (maybe someone clicks on the tile top left of it) and there you may need to decide which tile you want to be selected.

Another way would be to divide your panel into a panel of squares. But without drawing them of course. Imagine that each tile could have a square in the middle:

```
               /\
             /____\
           / |    | \
           \ |____| /
             \    /
               \/
```

something like that. so you only need to calculate if someone clicked inside the square.

Comment: No, each tile is 36 pixel wide andd 18 pixel height, and because it is isometric, all tile is diamond-shaped. Here is a pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mRul8.png

Comment: And here is my project: http://imgur.com/zfUi1eH, the beginX and beginY is near the top corner of the diamond.

Comment: @Bálint, I edited your question and added the code you posted and included the image. If you want to add information to your question, use the edit button on your post. Now to your problem: (nice game by the way) what I meant is, that you calculate the position of your tiles, so the same way you calculate it you can actually calculate on which tile your mouse clicks.

Comment: Thank you, my only idea was to calculate it with matrices.

Comment: sorry I saw your comment to late. Well that sounds actually like a good idea. I wouldn't know where to start right now :) and stick to the simple *backwards-calculating* method. Another approach would be that you create your own class `Tile` and when creating your game, you fill an array with your tiles and set the x and y position of each tile. So when the user clicks you iterate through the array and test if `mouseX>tile.getX()` and `mouseX<(tile.getX()+tile.getWidth())`... somehow like this.

Comment: I have the world in a simple 2 dimensional array, if i can rotate the array back, then it would be correct (i think). But i got the perfect idea, check the tile picking during the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for rendering

```
int posX = 10;
int posY = 0;      
static int beginY = 500-72;
static int beginX = 800-36;
static int newLineY = 60;
static int newLineX = 200;    

posY = ((0+1)*9)-9+beginY/2;
posX = ((beginX)/2)+18-(18*(0+1));
for (int y = 0; y <= world.length-1; y++) {
for (int x = 0; x <= world[y].length-1; x++) {
    if (world[y][x] == 1) {
        g.drawImage(grass, posX, posY, null);
        posX += 18;
        posY += 9;
    } else if (world[y][x] == 2) {
        g.drawImage(wall, posX, posY-38, null);
        posX += 18;
        posY += 9;
    } else if (world[y][x] == 3) {
        g.drawImage(stone, posX, posY, null);
        posX += 18;
        posY += 9;
    } else if (world[y][x] == 4) {
        g.drawImage(water, posX, posY, null);
        posX += 18;
        posY += 9;
    } else {
        posX += 18;
        posY += 9;
    }
    if ((y-pPosX) * (y-pPosX) + (x-pPosY) * (x-pPosY) <= 3*3 && world[y][x] != 0 && world[y][x] != 2 && world[y][x] != 4) {
        g.drawImage(hollow, posX-18, posY-9, null);
    }
    if (y == selectedX && x == selectedY) {
        g.drawImage(selected, posX-18, posY-9, null);
    }
    if (world2[y][x] == 9) {
        g.drawImage(character, posX-18, posY-53, null);
    }
}
posY = ((y+1)*9)+beginY/2;
posX = ((beginX)/2)-(18*(y+1));
}
```